# How to fix my MCTS-based AI for the Blokus game?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, artificial-intelligence, game-development, monte-carlo-tree-search

I'm working on an AI for the Blokus game using the Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS) algorithm. I've implemented the core of the algorithm, including the selection, expansion, simulation, and backpropagation phases. However, I'm facing some performance issues that make the AI incredibly slow and inefficient, especially when searching deeper into the game tree/running more simulation.
and ruining the view of the pieces in the game

```java
public class Mcts {
    private static final double EXPLORATION_CONSTANT = Math.sqrt(2);
    private static final int SIMULATION_ROUNDS = 1500;

    public Mcts() {
    }

    public Node chooseMove(State state) {
        int begin = State.debugCounter;
        // Create root node for MCTS tree
        Node rootNode = new Node(new State(state), null, null);
        // Perform MCTS simulations to choose move
        long t;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIMULATION_ROUNDS; i++) {
            //Selection
            t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Node selectedNode = select(rootNode);
//            System.out.println("selection time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
            //Expansion
            t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Node expandedNode = expand(selectedNode);
//            System.out.println("expandtion time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
            //Simulation
            t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            double result = simulate(expandedNode);
//            System.out.println("simulation time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
            //BackPropagation
            t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            backpropagate(expandedNode, result);
//            System.out.println("backProagation time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

        }
        // Select best move based on tree statistics
        Node bestChild = rootNode.children.stream().max(Comparator.comparingDouble(child ->
                (double) child.value / child.visits + EXPLORATION_CONSTANT * Math.sqrt(Math.log(rootNode.visits) / child.visits)
        )).orElse(null);

//        System.out.println("delta = " + (State.debugCounter - begin));
        State.debugCounter = 0;

        if (bestChild != null) {
            return bestChild;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Node select(Node node) {
        while (!node.isLeaf()) {
            node = node.selectChild();
        }
        return node;
    }

    private Node expand(Node node) {
        Duration deltaTime = Duration.ZERO;
        Instant time0 = Instant.now();

        State newGame = new State(node.state);
        Move move = newGame.getRandomUnexploredMove();
        if (move == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Instant time1 = Instant.now();

        newGame.playPiece(move);
        Instant time2 = Instant.now();
        newGame.advanceTurn();
        Node childNode = new Node(newGame, node, move);
        node.children.add(childNode);
//        System.out.println("============\nDuration = " + Duration.between(time0, time1));
//        time0 = time1;
//        time1 = time2;
//        System.out.println("Duration = " + Duration.between(time0, time1));
        return childNode;
    }

    private double simulate(Node node) {
        if (node == null) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        State simGame = new State(node.state);
        // Play random moves until game is over
        while (simGame.getGameState()==GameState.MIDDLE) {
            Move move = simGame.getRandomUnexploredMove();
            if (move != null) {
                simGame.playPiece(move);
                //simGame.printBoard();
            }
            else
                simGame.isGameOver();
        }
        //Return result of game
        BColor winner = simGame.getWinner();
        if (winner==node.state.getCurrentPlayer().getColor()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (winner == BColor.WHITE) {
            return  0.5;
        } else {
            return  0;
        }
    }

    private void backpropagate(Node node, double result) {
        Node tempNode = node;
        while (tempNode != null) {
            tempNode.visits++;
            tempNode.value += result;
            tempNode = tempNode.parent;
        }
    }
```

I have the full code here: [jayTheCreat/blokus](https://github.com/jayTheCreat/blokus.git)

I've tried profiling my code using various tools, and I found that the expand and simulation phases are taking the most time and work (Which begs the question is my genral algorihm even correct), and inside them, the `getRandomUnexploredMove()` method is also taking a lot of time (which is in the `State` class). I've already tried caching the moves, but that didn't seem to help much.

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to fix my code and make it run faster and better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reuse the MCTS (the tree) to some extent between moves? The root has changed, but there are still many useful nodes in the tree. Just an idea.